# Wrong calculation of price in shopping cart in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cart, shopping-cart

I write a cart for my shopping in Laravel but there is a wrong calculation in total price.
my Cart.php is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Cart {

    public $items;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if ($oldCart)
        {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function add($item , $id,$width,$height,$order,$count)
    {
        $storedItem = [
            'id' =>$item->id,
            'order' => $order,
            'qty' => 0,
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'priceperunit' => $item->priceperunit,
            'price' => $item->price,
            'item' => $item
        ];

        if ($this->items)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items))
            {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }

        if ($count)
        {
            $storedItem['qty'] += $count;
        }
        else
        {
            $storedItem['qty']++;
        }

        if ($storedItem['order'])
        {
            $storedItem['price'] = $storedItem['width'] * $storedItem['height'] * $storedItem['priceperunit'] * $storedItem['qty'];
            $this->items[] = $storedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
            $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        }

        if ($count)
        {
            $this->totalQty += $count;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->totalQty++;
        }       

        $this->totalPrice += $storedItem['price'];
    }
}
```

when I add only one item the total & quantity is ok, but when I add a second one of that item it's calculates the triple, and when I add it again it calculates the quadruple.

here is my cart items:

```
{
    "items": {
        "172": {
        "id": 172,
        "qty": 2,
        "price": 160,
        "item": {
            "id": 172,
            "name": "R3-60",
            "desc": null,
            "price": "80",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my cart total:

```
{
"totalPrice": 240,
"totalQty": 2
}
```

Comment: ```{
"items": {
"172": {
"id": 172,
"qty": 3,
"price": 240,
"item": {
"id": 172,
"name": "R3-60",
"desc": null,
"price": "80",
}
}
}
}``` and total is 
```{
"totalPrice": 480,
"totalQty": 3
}```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it way harder for yourself by trying to calculate totals on adding items. Most `Php` operations is not that costly, so i would calculate them when you need them.

```
class Cart {

    public $items;

    public function totalPrice() {
        return array_sum(array_column($this->items, 'price'));
    }

    public function totalQty() {
        return array_sum(array_column($this->items, 'qty'));
    }
}
```

Your data structure is very misleading as your code, combined with comments show something different, this is an idea of an alternative way of handling this problem.